# React table drawn by a map is very slow to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an accordion that when it is expanded will display a table which is drawn using a map based on data. There is less than 20 rows ever drawn but it takes a few seconds to load, this is not an api issue as the data is returned in less than 20 ms.

It doesn't feel normal that it would take this long to load, but if that's the case then I would like to display a loading icon until it is loaded. The issue I'm having with doing this is that I want to wait for the map to finish writing the table before displaying it, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to wait for this to happen.

Here is my code.

```
 <TableContainer component={Paper} >
    <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases" sx={{ p: 2 }}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell align="left"><b>Resource Id</b></TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left"><b>Resource Type</b></TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center"><b>Opened On</b></TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center"><b>Potential Savings</b></TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {props.data?.map((item, i) => (
          <TableRow key={i}>
            <TableCell>{item.resource_id}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{item.resource_type}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{item.observerd_at}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{formatCurrency(item.saving)}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
```

And the accordion which loaded the above in "AccountEvents"

```
      {props.accounts ?
    props.accounts.map((item, i) => (
      <Box key={item.account_id} sx={{ py: 2 }}>
        <Accordion onChange={handleChange(item.account_id)}>
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
            id="panel1bh-header"
          >
            <div className="row">
              <Typography align="left"><b>Account: </b>{item.account_name}</Typography>
              <Typography align="left"><b>Potential Monthly Savings: </b>{formatCurrency(item.total_saving)}</Typography>
            </div>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <div className="row">
              <Divider color="grey" />
              <Box sx={{ py: 2 }}>
                <Typography align="left">
                  <b>Account #: </b>{item.account_id}
                </Typography>
              </Box>
              <Divider color="grey" />
              <Box sx={{ py: 2 }}>
                <AccountEvents data={recommendations ? recommendations : null} />
              </Box>
            </div>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      </Box>
    ))
    : <Typography>No accounts to display</Typography>}
```

Here is my onChange function for the accordion.

```
  const handleChange = (index) => (event, isExpanded) => {
      setIndex(isExpanded ? index : undefined)
  };
```

This is called when the accordion is opened or closed. I have noticed that if I comment out setIndex it works fast (even while loading 20 or so rows). And even when I remove any api calls that a change in Index makes.

In other words, even if setIndex triggers nothing in my code, setting it when expanding the accordion slows it down considerably for some unknown reason.

Comment: that's weird, the api data gets loaded fast but rendering is slow, do you have any useEffects or any logic that could affect?

Comment: I do have two useEffects but they are unrelated to this.

Comment: Have you already tried using a virtualized list?

Comment: I have tried with a set list, look at my edit, it seems it's for some reason caused by changing the cost index value whenever expanding the accordion.

Comment: The small amount of markup you posted is fine, but please don't use the index as key. Can you give use the rest of the internals? Are those prebuilt components? Repro?

Comment: Added the full accordion, changed the key to account id instead of index but it's still slow. 

Expanding the same accordion is fast, but when I change the accordion (thus changing the account id and the setIndex) it's slow.

Comment: It's still not enough to provide a real answer. Can you give us a repro in codesandbox/codepen/...?
Judging from your comment, you could log out render passes and calls to your handleChange function. Maybe it gets called on mount -> setIndex retriggers renders and this happens n times while blocking your UI. Just a guess. Give us a repro :)

Comment: We need the full code of this component. You are saying that it's the setIndex which slows everything down, but we have no code to test and verify what is going on. One can never be too sure about these things when something is not working properly - who knows if you are using the [index, setIndex] state in some peculiar way that makes it slow.

Comment: It's possible that the slow down you're experiencing is due to the fact that the entire table is being re-rendered every time the accordion is expanded or collapsed, rather than just the rows that have changed. This can be especially noticeable if the data in the table is complex or requires a lot of processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### you are right & its not normal/good

i got curious about this and dug in using stackblitz. there is 100% an issue with nested data in the MUI tables and apparently you are not alone as others have similar rendering issues.

#### two suggestions

1. you can hide the nested table element until the element is toggled. [here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rw7fft) that shows the issue you described and a hackish solution that will need some cleanup to improve the slight stutter (i already tried a couple css only approaches but they didn't make a difference with the slow rendering issue)
2. there is a [paid edition of MUI](https://mui.com/pricing/) which comes with [mui data grid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) that is supposed to be better...

https://stackblitz-starters-rw7fft.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Dont pay for it! You can create your own table component in like an hour. Dont give money to that company.